# send a custom type to DLL

Tags: c#

I have created a custom type (StampDates) that consist of an InDate and an OutDate
A List of these objects is sent to a dll that does some math on it, and return a value.For now, this is just 1 set of dates, but I will send filled Lists, and the dll will return a sum of them all.

The method in the dll expects a list of the type `<StampDates>`:

```
public int NumDays(List<StampDates> dates)
{
    foreach (StampDates datums in dates)
    {
        DateTime indatum = datums.InDateTime;
        DateTime uitdatum = datums.OutDateTime;
        if ((DateTime.Now.Date - indatum).TotalDays <= 180)
        {
            Days = (uitdatum-indatum  ).Days;
        }

    }

    return Days;
}
```

This works fine, but because I need to create that list in my external form, I need to define the custom type there also.
This gives a type conversion error between the Form.StampDates and the DLL.Stampdates

```
public class StampDates
{
    private DateTime inDateTime;

    public DateTime InDateTime
    {
        get { return inDateTime; }
        set { inDateTime = value; }
    }

    private DateTime outDateTime;

    public DateTime OutDateTime
    {
        get { return outDateTime; }
        set { outDateTime = value; }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why don't you use the Dll's `StampDates`? And where do you declare `Days`? Should not compile, imho.

Comment: I'd also recommend to code against interfaces ( i.e. `IEnumerable<StampDates>` instead of `List<StampDates>` )

Comment: *"I need to define the custom type there also"* - If you're defining a new type then you have two different types.  Instead of defining a new one, use the same one.  (Possibly by translating from one type to the other in the layer that references the DLL, if you don't want other layers referencing it.)

Comment: See, even if `Form.StampDates` and `Dll.StampDates` have the same name and are implemented the same, for the compiler, they are two different types. So, this is totally expected.

Comment: What does "sent to a dll" mean? Are you referencing this dll? Do you use reflection? COM?

Comment: ^^ I personally even wouldn't have a `StampDates` implementation in the Dll at all. I'd have an interface `IStampDates` and the method taking a parameter of `IEnumerable<IStampDates>`. Where you define the actual implementation is on another page.

Comment: @Fildor : can you give me just a small example of what you are saying? I'm new to interfaces, and I don't see how I can add a collection of StampDates items to work with.

Comment: Well, an interface is just a "contract". So if you create an `IStampDates` interface, you are basically saying "Whatever you give me, it has to have these public accessible properties and these methods". And if you have a parameter of `IEnumerable<IStampDates>` then it's basically "I expect some collection, that I can iterate, which contains items that have these props and methods". That way you are free to pass any datastructure and implementation that meet those expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the usage of interfaces here:

DLL:

```
// In the dll we do not care about the actual implementation.
// To perform our task, we just need this to have two properties:
public interface IStampDates 
{
    // Implementations must have these read/write properties
    DateTime InDateTime {get; set;}  // We even could make those readonly ...
    DateTime OutDateTime {get; set;}
}

// in the class that contains the method ...
public int NumDays(IEnumerable<IStampDates> dates)
{
      // Implementation has no dependency other than dotnet framework (for IEnumerable)
}
```

In the consuming App:

```
// Implementation of the IStampDates interface
class StampDates : IStampDates
{
    public DateTime InDateTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime OutDateTime {get; set;}
}

// Consuming part somewhere in a method, perhaps
List<IStampDates> stampDateList = new List<IStampDates>();
// ... populate list
stampDateList.Add( new StampDates() { InDateTime = ..., OutDatTime = ... });

// Call Dll
int days = dll.NumDays(stampDateList);
// assuming "dll" is an instance of the class that contains `NumDays`
```

So, your App has a dependency to the dll. That's fine. But your dll has no dependency outside itself or the framework (which is kind of unavoidable).
That means: if you use this dll in another App, the actual implementation of `StampDates` can be totally different, as long as it implements the Dll's interface of `IStampDates`.

The point of this being: If you use an interface here, it doesn't matter what the actual *runtime* type it is you are passing (given, it implements the interface). So it could be defined in the App, in the dll (the app should then use it, not create a (code)copy) or even in a third shared dependency. All depends on how you structure your solution.

Comment: thanks Fildor for your example. i was able to get it up and running, and I will try to make sense of it all in my head !

Comment: If you are new to the concept, take your time. It will get easier the more you use it.